# Laravel Eloquents relational query to get all field Data

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, foreign-keys, eloquent

Still experimenting with Eloquents relational queries and I wonder how do I have in my query result the `setup` field in my transitional table if the the structure is the following

having table campaign_networks_relationhsips

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 ID | networks_id | campaigns_id | setup                                         
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 1  | 1           | 1            | {"username":"username","password":"password"} 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 2  | 1           | 2            | {"username":"username","password":"password"} 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

campaigns

```
+-------------------+
 ID | campaign_name                                          
+-------------------+
 1  | some name 
+-------------------+
 2  | test 
+-------------------+
```

networks

```
+-------------------+
 ID | network_name                                          
+-------------------+
 1  | network1 
+-------------------+
 2  | network2 
+-------------------+
```

than in my Camnpaigns model

```
public function networks() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Td\Reports\Networks\Networks',  'campaign_networks_relationhsips');
}
```

and calling from controller

```
   public function getNetworks($id = null) {
        $campaign = \Td\Reports\Campaigns\Campaigns::with('networks')->where('id', $id)->first();
        foreach ($campaign->networks as $network) {
             var_dump($network->network); //I have this Field
             var_dump($network->setup); // I do not habe this Field !!!!
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function networks() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Td\Reports\Networks\Networks',  'campaign_networks_relationhsips')
       ->withPivot(['setup', .. any other field you might want .. ]);
}

// then in the foreach loop you have:
...
   $network->pivot->setup;
```